# Установить 24-часовой формат даты linux

Tags: linux

Друзья, всем привет! Не могу найти информацию о том, как установить 24-часовой формат даты на сервере linux (Ubuntu).

При вводе в консоль команды **date** выводится

`Tue Jan 10 07:52:54 PM +05 2023`

А мне нужно, чтобы было в 24-часовом формате. Не 07:52, а 19:52

Comment: как-то так, суть в создании алиаса для данной команды с нужным форматом [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696715/permanently-change-the-output-format-of-the-date-command-in-my-kali-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696715/permanently-change-the-output-format-of-the-date-command-in-my-kali-linux)

Comment: См. форматы в `date --help` (%T время в 24-часовом формате)

Comment: я бы скорее предположил, что вопрос вообще в настройке более подходящей _локали_ в системе, а не только date. LC_TIME в частности

Comment: `+05` — а вот этот фрагмент весьма странно выглядит. согласно man-у, /bin/date выдаёт подобный фрагмент для формата `%:::z`, но я такого фрагмента в `/usr/share/i18n/locales/` не нашёл. было бы интересно взглянуть на вывод программы `locale` (без аргументов) из этой вашей системы. приложите его, пожалуйста, к тексту вопроса, нажав [edit].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

вообще программа `/bin/date` берёт информацию о формате вывода из базы данных локалей (locales). текущие установки локали можно посмотреть, вызвав без аргументов программу:

```
$ locale
```

а с помощью вот такого вызова можно узнать формат для текущей локали:

```
$ locale -c d_t_fmt
```

вот этот кусочек (из вашего примера) — `07:52:54 PM` — программой `/bin/date` выводится для формата `%r` (см. `$ man date`: «locale's 12-hour clock time (e.g., 11:11:04 PM)»).

вы можете увидеть упоминание этого формата, запустив предыдущую команду.

переопределить же формат даты/времени можно переменной окружения `LC_TIME`. примеры:

```
$ env -i LC_TIME=ru_RU.utf8 /bin/date
Вт 10 янв 2023 19:15:48 MSK
$ env -i LC_TIME=en_US.utf8 /bin/date
Tue 10 Jan 2023 07:15:59 PM MSK
```

выберите подходящую локаль (не содержащую в `d_t_fmt` формата `%r`). их вообще много, см. вывод:

```
$ grep -r d_t_fmt /usr/share/i18n/locales/ | grep -v '%r'
```

вообще даже ru_RU подойдёт под вашу задачу:

```
$ env -i LC_TIME=ru_RU.utf8 /bin/date
Вт 10 янв 2023 19:26:29 MSK
```

но можно и на какой-нибудь англоязычной остановиться:

```
$ grep -r d_t_fmt /usr/share/i18n/locales/ | grep -v '%r' | grep en_
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_IL:d_t_fmt  "%a %d %b %Y %T"
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_ZM:d_t_fmt     "%a %d %b %Y %T %Z"
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_NG:d_t_fmt     "%a %d %b %Y %T"
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_IN:d_t_fmt     "%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p"
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_AG:d_t_fmt     "%a %d %b %Y %T %Z"
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB:d_t_fmt     "%a %d %b %Y %T %Z"
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_DK:d_t_fmt  "%Y-%m-%dT%T %Z"
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_PH:d_t_fmt     "%A, %d %B, %Y %I:%M:%S %p"
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_AU:d_t_fmt     "%a %d %b %Y %T"
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_HK:d_t_fmt     "%A, %B %d, %Y %p%I:%M:%S"
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_IE:d_t_fmt     "%a %d %b %Y %T"
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_ZA:d_t_fmt     "%a %d %b %Y %T"
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_NZ:d_t_fmt     "%a %d %b %Y %T"
```

en_GB (great britain), или en_NZ (new zealand), или ещё какую-нибудь:

```
$ env -i LC_TIME=en_GB.utf8 /bin/date
Tue 10 Jan 19:30:10 MSK 2023
$ env -i LC_TIME=en_NZ.utf8 /bin/date
Tue 10 Jan 2023 19:30:25 MSK
```

---

но тут ещё такая засада, что если вдруг определена переменная `LC_ALL` (а она часто бывает определена), то значения других «локале-задающих» переменных `LC_*` игнорируются. поэтому, если она в вашем окружении определена, то менять надо уже её, а не `LC_TIME`.

---

ах, да, совсем забыл написать про то, как менять. если у вас debian-подобный дистрибутив, то вручную подправить можно где-то в районе `/etc/default/locale`, ну или совсем уж по-простому:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

в других дистрибутивах смотрите документацию к ним.

Comment: помимо `%r` может быть ещё и, например, `%I:%M:%S %p`. в приведённых в ответе это локали `en_IN` (india) и `en_PH` (philippines). ну и в другом порядке те же части `%p%I:%M:%S` у `en_HK` (hong kong).

Comment: через консоль не получилось, но, добравшись до файла /etc/default/locale я победил эту проблему! спасибо за помощь!